# click on any button but one to show alert jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of buttons, I want the alert shows up when clicking any button but `#button3`

**HTML**

```
 <div id="Icon"></div>
 <div id="button1">Click 1</div>
 <div id="button2">Click 2</div>
 <div id="button3">Click 3</div>
  ...
 <div id="buttonn">Click n</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  IconDeactived = function(){

  if(!$("#button3") is clicked){ alert();

  $("#Icon").css({
     "background-image" : "url('icons/poll_disabled.png')",
     "pointer-events" : "none"
  });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the selector to only listen to non-button3 elements.

```js
//only those that start with "button" and not button3
$('div[id$="Icon"]:not(#ExcludeIcon)').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Icon"></div>
<div id="PollIcon">Click 1</div>
<div id="GifIcon">Click 2</div>
<div id="ExcludeIcon">Click 3</div>
<div id="ToolIcon">Click n</div>
```

Comment: awesome approach, the problem not all the divs has similar id names,  but all contains the match `Icon`, like this: `PollIcon, GifIcon,ImageIcon,ToolIcon,VideoIcon` something like `'div[id^="...Icon"]:not(#button3)'` would work for me, is that syntax correct?

Comment: Then you can use div[id$=Icon]` ($ = ends with)

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the **[`:not` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** to target all `<div>` elements that are not `#button3`:

```js
$('div:not(#button3)').on("click", function() {
  console.log('Clicked element: ' + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Icon"></div>
<div id="button1">Click 1</div>
<div id="button2">Click 2</div>
<div id="button3">Click 3 -- Won't trigger</div>
...
<div id="buttonn">Click n</div>
```

Obviously you're likely to have more `<div>` elements that, so you'll probably need to change your selector, but the general principle remains the same; simply target all elements that you want the click handler to apply to, then use `:not` to target the subset you want to exclude.